# requestLocationUpdates do not work at all

Tags: android, gps

What i am trying to ping an url with device's gps location.

in onCreate i have this

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

and MyLocationListener class at below

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    private final String TAG = "Walkie.LocationListener";
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
        String latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://url.com/gps.php?longitude=" + longitude + "&latitude=" + latitude);

            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30); // mTimeout is in seconds
            urlc.connect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Status changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Provider disabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Provider enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Status changed");
    }

}
```

gps.php is not pinged at all, is there something i am doing wrong?

I have those permissions in manifest

> android.permission.INTERNET
>
> android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: hi, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

GPS has a cold start some time it may take several minutes if it is starting after a long time.

Ensure you are having the GPS permission also in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
```

Also ensure it is enabled and in working state.

Comment: its still same, url is still not pinged